# AlertDialog. When to change the style of the message?

Tags: android, android-alertdialog

I want to have the message of an alertdialog displayed with a monospace font, so I wrote this code, which work nice:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext());
builder.setMessage("message");
...
AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
dialog.show();
TextView messageView = dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
messageView.setTypeface(Typeface.MONOSPACE);
```

My question is about the order of the calls: you need `dialog.show()` to be called in order to call `dialog.findViewById`, otherwise you get a null pointer.
It does not sound logical to show something and then to change it. I would have preferred to build it with the right style and then show it.

Is there a way to do it like that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prepare your own `TextView` or any `View` Programmatically or in XML as a custom `View` the show it like:

```
builder.setView(getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.YourLayout, null))
```

Now `YourLayout` should have all the styles you like from now. Otherwise it will be hard to call `findViewById` without the Dialog view on the Screen!!

Comment: That's great and **Happy Coding!**